# Creating a function to avoid code repetition

Tags: vba, visio

I have some vba code in Excel to automate Visio and I have to create multiple text boxes. I currently do it like this:

```
        Set textbox1 = vsoDocument.Pages(PageName).DrawRectangle(1,1,1,3)
        textbox1.LineStyle = "Text Only"
        textbox1.FillStyle = "Text Only"
        textbox1.CellsSRC(visSectionParagraph, 0, visHorzAlign).FormulaU = "0" 'Align Left
        textbox1.CellsSRC(visSectionCharacter, 0, visCharacterSize).FormulaU = "6 pt"
        textbox1.Characters.Text = "Text goes here"
        textbox1.Characters.CharProps(visCharacterStyle) = 17#
```

However I would like to move this to a function, but I still need to have the box be able to be referenced by name as I perform other task on it later in the script. I have tried to to make a function to perform this:

```
Function AddTextBox(vName, x1, y1, x2, y2, align, tSize, textchar)
    Set vName = vsoDocument.Pages(PageName).DrawRectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    vName.LineStyle = "Text Only"
    vName.FillStyle = "Text Only"
    vName.CellsSRC(visSectionParagraph, 0, visHorzAlign).FormulaU = align
    vName.CellsSRC(visSectionCharacter, 0, visCharacterSize).FormulaU = tSize
    vName.Characters.Text = textchar
End Function
```

And called it like this:

```
test = AddTextBox("textbox1", 1, 1, 1, 3, 0, "6 pt", "Text goes here")
```

However I get an 'object required' 424 error. Any VBA functions I have read seem to be used to return a value, rather than used to avoid repeating code.

Is it possible to simplify my code and prevent repeating myself with this method?

Comment: Is `vsoDocument` a global variable?

Comment: No; vsoDocument is dimensioned in the  Sub. I fixed this problem by importing it to the function.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to create an object, but the object you are creating is being passed in as a string. Do something like this instead:

```
Dim oText as Object
Function AddTextBox(oText, x1, y1, x2, y2, align, tSize, textchar)
    Set oText= vsoDocument.Pages(PageName).DrawRectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    oText.LineStyle = "Text Only"
    oText.FillStyle = "Text Only"
    oText.CellsSRC(visSectionParagraph, 0, visHorzAlign).FormulaU = align
    oText.CellsSRC(visSectionCharacter, 0, visCharacterSize).FormulaU = tSize
    oText.Characters.Text = textchar
End Function
```

This will allow you to create a textbox object using the function, but it raises the fact that the function isn't returning any values and thus should actually be a sub. To counteract this, you could do something like this instead:

```
    Function AddTextBox(x1, y1, x2, y2, align, tSize, textchar)
        Set oText= vsoDocument.Pages(PageName).DrawRectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2)
        oText.LineStyle = "Text Only"
        oText.FillStyle = "Text Only"
        oText.CellsSRC(visSectionParagraph, 0, visHorzAlign).FormulaU = align
        oText.CellsSRC(visSectionCharacter, 0, visCharacterSize).FormulaU = tSize
        oText.Characters.Text = textchar

        Set AddTextBox = oText
    End Function
```

And call it like this:

```
Dim oText as Object
Set oText = AddTextBox(x1, y1, y2, align, tSize, textchar)
```

Where the args of the function are the variables you want to pass in.

Revised code per comments from the OP:

```
Function AddTextBox(oText as Object, x1 as Long, y1 as Long, x2 as Long, y2 as Long, align, tSize as Long, textchar, PageName as String) as Boolean
    If Not vsoDocument.Pages(PageName) is Nothing Then
        Set oText= vsoDocument.Pages(PageName).DrawRectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2)
        With oText
            .LineStyle = "Text Only"
            .FillStyle = "Text Only"
            .CellsSRC(visSectionParagraph, 0, visHorzAlign).FormulaU = align
            .CellsSRC(visSectionCharacter, 0, visCharacterSize).FormulaU = tSize
            .Characters.Text = textchar
    Else
         AddTextBox = True
    End If
End Function
```

You would then call it like this:

```
Dim oText as Object
If Not AddTextBox(oText, x1, y1, y2, align, tSize, textchar, PageName) Then
    If Not oText is Nothing Then

        ' Just to test whether oText is set or not.
    Else
        Debug.Print "Error when setting oText"
    End if
Else
    Debug.Print "vsoDocument.Pages(" & PageName & ") is not an object!"
End If
```

You certainly dont need this many If blocks and there are better ways of handling these If returns within the function, ill leave that up to you to refine once you get the function working though. Just be sure you are passing in a valid pagename, and use the above example to ensure the object is being found.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Is it maybe the document reference 'vsoDocument' that's breaking it? I've had to reference the PageName as an argument as it was coming in to the function as empty.

Comment: The error you received happens whenever a command is expecting an object but it last given one. This certainly can be the case with your vso document. Once I get on my computer I can add something to your code to check for this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by setting the Visio Document type with `As Visio.Document`. Then all the problems just melted away. Here's the final function:

```
Function AddTextBox(vd As Visio.Document, PageName, x1, y1, x2, y2, align, tSize, textchar)
    Set vName = vd.Pages(PageName).DrawRectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    vName.LineStyle = "Text Only"
    vName.FillStyle = "Text Only"
    vName.CellsSRC(visSectionParagraph, 0, visHorzAlign).FormulaU = align
    vName.CellsSRC(visSectionCharacter, 0, visCharacterSize).FormulaU = tSize
    vName.Characters.Text = textchar
    Set AddTextBox = vName
End Function
```

It's then called like so:

```
Set TextBox1= AddTextBox(vsoDocument, Page1, 0.7, 8, 0.5, 8, 0, "6 pt", "Text goes here")
```